# Ecommerce con Next.js y Medusa - Error al instalar Admin Panel

Tags: nextjs, medusa

Estoy tratando de crear una tienda con https://github.com/medusajs/vercel-commerce

Si sigo los pasos indicados en ese Readme, la tienda se instala perfecto. Tengo endpoints para consultar mis productos en `localhost:9000` que puedo probar en postman, el front-end funcionando en `localhost:3000`, pero no se como acceder al panel de administracion y en ese github no indica nada.

Entonces googleando encontré e intente seguir estos pasos https://docs.medusajs.com/admin/quickstart

Instalo el admin, agrego esto a los plugins

```
 {
    resolve: "@medusajs/admin",
    /** @type {import('@medusajs/admin').PluginOptions} */
    options: {
      autoRebuild: true,
    },
  }
```

y si corro `npm run dev` o `npx medusa develop` recibo el error

> [@medusajs/admin] Could not find the admin UI build files. Please run
> "medusa-admin build" or enable "autoRebuild" in the plugin options to
> build the admin UI.

En mi `package.json` tengo el script

```
"build:admin": "cross-env medusa-admin build"
```

Y si corro `npm run build:admin` recibo un error gigante donde la primer parte dice esto:

> [@medusajs/admin]
> [{"moduleIdentifier":"javascript/esm|/Users/agustinguerra/eljardin/el-jardin/el-jargin/medusa/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/Users/agustinguerra/eljardin/el-jardin/el-jargin/medusa/node_modules/prism-react-renderer/dist/index.mjs","moduleName":"./node_modules/prism-react-renderer/dist/index.mjs","loc":"763:929","message":"Module
> parse failed: Unexpected token (763:929)\nFile was processed with
> these loaders:\n * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js\nYou
> may need an additional loader to handle the result of these
> loaders.\n|

Estoy algo perdido, sospecho que me falta instalar algo mas, pero no me doy cuenta cual es el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que hay alguna libreria con la cual el componente `admin` tiene inconvenientes. La solucion fue instalar el admin con la bandera `--legacy-peer-deeps`

```
npm install @medusajs/admin --legacy-peer-deps
```

Despues de esto, el backend finalmente se encuentra corriendo en `localhost:9000/app` y ahora sí se puede acceder desde el navegador.